# Monoid type annotation

Tags: scala, monoids

In the book Functional Programming in Scala I see the following signature:

```
def productMonoid[A,B](A: Monoid[A], B: Monoid[B]): Monoid[(A,B)]
```

The description says that:

```
if types A and B are monoids, then the tuple type (A, B) is also a monoid
```

I have a difficulty in understanding the following part:

```
A: Monoid[A]
```

A is of type Monoid which takes itself as a type parameter? How to understand that?

Comment: Where'd you see that signature? On page 190 of this book, I see `trait Monoid[A] {
def op(a1: A, a2: A): A
def zero: A
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here: `A: Monoid[A]` the is just a variable name, it can also be written as `a: Monoid[A]` or `param1: Monoid[A]`. It it a bit of convention to give such variable names, for example in most cases variable name for a functor is F - `F: Function[A]` and M for a Monad - `M: Monad[A]`:

```
abstract class SomeClass[TC[_], A](param: TC[A]) {
  implicit val M: Monad[TC]
  ... // other code
}
```

It's more readable and clear if you see something like `M.point[TC]` where M is an instance of a `Monad`.

**Added**

And `A: Monoid[A]` is not a type annotation at all. Type parameters are written in square brackets:

def productMonoid **[A,B]** (params...), so in this variant:

```
def productMonoid[A: Monoid,B](params...)
```

Yes `Monoid[A]` is a type class for `A` type, it's desugared into:

```
def productMonoid[A,B](params...)(implicit val $ev: Monoid[A])
```

This means that `Monoid` is a type constructor which takes a type `A` and constructs a type `Monoid[A]` for `$ev`.

Comment: to me it would be more readable using lower case ´m.point [TC]´ or even better as ´ monad.point[TC]´. I understand being used to math notation but it detracts from general accessibility

Comment: I might agree with `monad.point[TC]` variant, standard variable naming convention, but `m` maybe it's a readable, but not that clear as all one-letter lower case name like `x` `d` `o` and others, where you have thousands of code it's not totally unreadable

Comment: @Alexlv You say that A: Monoid[A] is not a type annotation. I read the description here [link](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html) and still do not understand why it is not. Could you explain?

Comment: @rarry that's scala notation for types. `value: Type` is similar to `Type value` in Java/C++/C#. In your example just says that value `A` is of type `Monoid[A]`, just in scala type comes after the variable name

Comment: @Alexlv And they say that `value: Type` is type annotation, like `A: Monoid[A]`. Or I am completely missing something.

Comment: @rarry yes in line `A: Monoid[A]` A has a type `Monoid[A]`. Monoid is a type constructor, it's not a pure type as Int or String, it's more general. To become a pure type it need some other type, in your example it takes type `A` as a parameter and return new type `Monoid[A]`

Comment: @rarry I guess you just need to read about type constructors and kinds (higher-kinded type)

Comment: @Alexlv I just want to fully understand this. You say that `value: Type` is type annotation while `A: Monoid[A]` is not, simply because Monoid is a higher kinded type?

Comment: @rarry it's a type annotation. You just wrote `productMonoid[A,B](A: Monoid[A], B: Monoid[B])` here `A` and `B` are type parameters and variable names, i though you've meant short syntax for implicit parameters which should be written in square brackets like `productMonoid[A: Monoid, B: Monoid]`, not the best example it case of names and letters

Comment: @Alexlv I fully appreciate your answer, but there is one more thing that I have doubts about. You also wrote that I should read about type constructors **and** higher-kinded types. Are you implying that these are two different things?

Comment: @Alexlv Ok. Now I fully understand. I was just mislead by `Joshua D. Suereth` sentence in his book `Scala in Depth`. On page 136 He wrote: `Higher-kinded types are also called type constructors
because they’re used to construct types.`

Comment: @rarry To understand this better i recommend you to watch [this](http://vimeo.com/13518456) talk it will explain everything